# R: Extract multi-values attribute (without delimiter)

Tags: r, dataframe

For example, I have the following `dataframe` called `person`:

```
|name  |       hobbies       |
------------------------------
 Jeff  |  gamesbasketball
 Linda |  hikingtennisreading
```

I want to convert the above table into the following table (let's call it `person_unwind`):

```
|name  |  hobbies|
------------------
 Jeff  |  games
 Jeff  |  basketball
 Linda |  hiking
 Linda |  tennis
 Linda |  reading
```

Somehow, I knew all the values in `hobbies` are "enum"s. Specifically, I have another `dataframe` called `all_hobbies`:

```
| all_hobbies |
---------------
  games
  basketball
  hiking
  tennis
  reading
```

My initial thought was to insert `,` between distinct values in `hobbies` using regex (loop over the whole `person` table), and then I can use `seperate_rows()` in `dplyr` library to "unwind" the `hobbies` attribute.

Is there any other good way to convert `person` to `person_unwind` given `all_hobbies`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the second dataset to extract all words into a `list` and then `unnest` the `list` column to expand the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
person %>%
   mutate(hobbies = str_extract_all(hobbies, 
                str_c(all_hobbies$all_hobbies, collapse="|"))) %>%
   unnest(c(hobbies))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  name  hobbies   
#  <chr> <chr>     
#1 Jeff  games     
#2 Jeff  basketball
#3 Linda hiking    
#4 Linda tennis    
#5 Linda reading
```

#### data

```
person <- data.frame(name = c("Jeff", "Linda"), 
   hobbies = c("gamesbasketball", "hikingtennisreading"))
all_hobbies <- data.frame(all_hobbies = c("games", "basketball",
         "hiking", "tennis", "reading"))
```